# Autorotaion Broadcast Intent?

Tags: android, android-widget, autorotate

Does Auto rotation change (via Settings -> Display -> Autorotation) sends Broad cast intent?

If Yes, then which?

If no, then how to detect that user has changed auto rotation preference? Actually I am creating Auto rotation widget and I want to update the image of widget according to the new auto rotation status each time, if user manually changes it from Settings.

Answer (score 1):

The ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED is broadcasted. However, you cannot register to it through manifest file. I never built a screen widget so I don't know if you can register it on any context or not.

Anyhow, here's the link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED

Comment: Thanks..Ribeiro for your answer, I have to try it ,then i will accept the answer.